# How can I display translated author role name in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, translate

Using this function in functions.php works but it displays the slug name for example: *administrator*

```
function get_author_role() {
    $userauthorid = get_the_author_meta( 'id' );
    $user_info = get_userdata($userauthorid );
    echo $user_info->roles['name']; 
}
```

I want it to show the translated role name.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
`translate_user_role()` : Unfortunately, as it seems this function wasn't meant to be executed in Wordpress Frontend. I thought [that issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37539) was over!

There are two solutions to this problem :

- Solution 1:
  Load the Administration' Textdomain in frontend :

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_admin_textdomain_in_front' )    function load_admin_textdomain_in_front() {
           if ( ! is_admin() ) {
               load_textdomain( 'default', WP_LANG_DIR . '/admin-' . get_locale() . '.mo' );
           }    }
```

- Solution 2:

User roles are just few words, so I just made this function to pick the translation of Role' name from an array of translations.

```
function get_author_info() {
      $post_data = get_post_data(); 
      $author_data = get_userdata($post_data->post_author);  
      $author_roles = $author_data->roles;
        $role = $author_data->roles[0];
        $rolesfr = array('editor'=>'&Eacute;diteur','administrator'=>'Administrateur','author'=>'Auteur','contributor'=>'Contributeur','subscriber'=>'Abonn&eacute;');     
        echo $rolesfr[$role] ;
}
```

On a multilingual website, you could add an argument to this function to switch for the active language. Or use the first solution.

Comment: Did you tried any ot those solutions in the update?

Comment: I tried solution 1. but it doesn`t work too. I forced to use IF else and echo code to display what i want.

Comment: Sorry Wordpress update concerning that function and it's workaround are not clarified yet ! But the 2nd solution I posted here is faster and cleaner than multiple if statements. Array lookup is even faster than switch case....

Comment: Merci Bilel. I`ll try Array lookup if it is faster.